# How to send a variable from a PHP loop to Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, modal-window

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
     <?
     $i=1;
     while ($u=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
     ?> 
     <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Sport</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $u['sport_id'];?></td>
            <td>
            <a id="modal_window" href="#" rel="open">Make Question</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
     <?php
     $i++;
     } 
     ?>
     </table>
```

The following modal window is opened when someone clicks on "Make Question":

```
            <div id="mascara"></div>
            <div id="ventana">
            <a class="ventanatitulo" href="#" rel="close">Close Window</a>
            <h2>Write your question:</h2><br/>
            <form>
            <input type="text" id="question"/>
            <br />
            </form>
            <a href="#" onClick="ajax_question();"/>Send question</a>
            </div>
```

What I want to do, is that every time someone clicks on "Make Question",  capture into a variable the question that was written on the modal window (no problem to do this), and the sport_id that was clicked (I DON´T KNOW HOW TO DO THIS!!)

This is the code for the modal window:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
    $('a[rel="open"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var ancho = $(window).width();
        var alto = $(document).height();

        var mascara = $("#mascara");
        var ventana = $("#ventana");

        mascara.css({
            "width" : ancho,
            "height" :  alto
        });

        mascara.fadeIn("fast", function() {

            ventana.css({
                "top" : (alto / 3) - (ventana.height() / 2),
                "left" : (ancho / 2) - (ventana.width() / 2)
            });

            ventana.fadeIn("fast");
        });
    });

    $("a[rel='close']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ventana").fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $("#mascara").fadeOut("fast");
        });
    }); 
});
```

And finally this is the code where I want to capture all the variables and send them to page1.php:

```
function ajax_question(){
var question=$('#question').val(); //WRITTED QUESTION IS CAPTURED WITHOUT PROBLEM!
var sport_id= //HOW DO I CAPTURE THE SPORT_ID THAT WAS CLICKED?
$.ajax({
    url:'page1.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'text/html',
    data:'question='+question + '&sport_id='+sport_id,
    success: function(return){
                some code...
    }
});
}
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to grab the previous sibling with jQuery, get the Sport ID value from your `<td>SPORT ID</td>` clause and give it as a parameter to the opened window which stores it in a `hidden input field`.

Here's a sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
    $('a[rel="open"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tmp_sport_id = $(this).parent().prev().text();
        alert(tmp_sport_id);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYCm7/1/)

**Important Note:**

When using element IDs such as `<a id="modal_window" href="#" rel="open">Make Question</a>` in your loop, you should be careful that IDs are **unique**. You are not allowed to use the same ID twice. Change that to `class="modal_window"`.

Comment: Good solution. Perhaps you should mention, though, that IDs need to be unique. OP should use `class=` instead of `id=modal_window`.

Comment: Thank you very much jsFiddle for your answer. Just 2 more questions:

Comment: 1) How do I send the var tmp_sport_id to function ajax_question?  2) How can I capture the variable sport_id if it is on the following link, and where should I put it:                         <a id="modal_window" href="#" rel="open" How do I write the variable sport_id here?>Make Question</a>
Thanks again!

Comment: The answer to 1) is in the answer I provided (hidden input field) and the answer to 2) is `<a id="modal_window" href="#" rel="open" title="SPORT_ID">Make Question</a>`

Comment: Thanks BassemDy, but I'm still stuck! 1) If I put this code on the opened window: <input type="hidden" id="id_sport" value="how do I capture the sport_id clicked?"/>   2) Which is the correct code to use in step of var tmp_sport_id = $(this).parent().prev().text(); to capture the sport_id from title?

Comment: 1) `$("id_sport").val()` you need to make sure the ID there is always the one clicked (by clearing it out when the window is closed etc, u need to cover all scenarios) 2) `$(this).attr('title')` You really need to do some research on how to use jQuery, I can't help you past thing point. All your questions have answers on Stack Overflow already.